# Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Tags: swift

Please help! I am experiencing an app crash.

public enum memberships {
case noMembership
case paid
case freeTrial
case trialExpired
}

public class DataManager {

```
private static let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
private static let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

private static let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(user?.uid ?? "")

static var currentStatus: memberships? = nil

/**
 Get's the current user's info from Firebase
 and returns the info as a User object
 */
class func getUser(completion: @escaping (User?) -> ()) {
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
```

//                UIPasteboard.general.string = uuid

```
            let uuid = snapshot.key
            let name = value["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let email = value["email"] as? String ?? ""
            let dateJoined = value["dateJoined"] as? String ?? ""
            let membershipString = value["membership"] as? String
            let alertsStartTime = value["alertsStartTime"] as? String ?? ""
            let alertsEndTime = value["alertsEndTime"] as? String ?? ""
            let alertsFrequency = value["alertsFrequency"] as? Int ?? 1
            let alertsType = value["alertsType"] as? String ?? ""
            let isEnable = value["isEnable"] as? Bool ?? true
            
            
            //Gets users current membership
            var membershipStatus: memberships!
            if membershipString == "Paid" {
                membershipStatus = .paid
            }else if membershipString == "NoMembership" {
                membershipStatus = .noMembership
            }else{
                membershipStatus = Utils.getUserMembershipStatus(dateJoined: dateJoined)
            }
            
           let user = User(uuid: uuid, name: name, email: email, dateJoined: dateJoined, membership: membershipStatus, alertsStartTime: alertsStartTime, alertsEndTime: alertsEndTime, alertsType: alertsType, alertsFrequency: alertsFrequency, isEnable: isEnable)
            completion(user)
            
        }else{
            completion(nil)
        }
        
      }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the crash message?

Comment: Please don't link to random external resources - who knows what is *really* behind that link?

Comment: your ```user``` object is empty. So ```user?.uid``` is nil. Which means ```child(user?.uid ?? "") ->  child("")```.  Firebase does not accept empty strings as key values. So make sure user user is logged in this case or use different key value

Comment: PS right now there are several links in the "related" section with the same message

Comment: Hello @great8 If you are using firebase database then make sure that child exist with the name of the user?.uid. If there is no child present with that user?.uid sting it'll crash

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your `user` object is empty. So `user?.uid` is `nil`. Which means `child(user?.uid ?? "") ->  child("")`.

Firebase does not accept empty strings as key values (It also does not accepts strings which includes `'.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''` as keys).

So in your case make sure user is logged or use different key value.

Comment: The problem is that it does not crash every time, just occasionally on the first cold launch. After the crash after the first cold launch, the app runs fine. After doing some research, it seems that it has something to do with the issue discussed here: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0. Any advice on how to implement this in my code? Many thanks!